# Twilio Screen Caller with Voicemail

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

My goal is to have the ability to screen incoming calls, and send them to voicemail.  The below code does the screening correctly, however if I answer the call and and then just hangup the call is dropped instead of directing it to voicemail.  How can I accomplish this?

```
<Say>Please wait while we connect you to Aaron. Calls may be recorded for quality assurance purposes.</Say>

<Dial action="voicemail.php?email=aaron" timeout="15">
  <Number url="screen-caller.xml">+11231231234</Number>
</Dial>
```

screen-caller.xml:

```
<Response>
    <Gather action="handle-screen-input.php" numDigits="1">
            <Say>To accept, press 1.</Say>
    </Gather>
    <!-- If customer doesn't input anything, prompt and try again. -->
    <Say>Sorry, I didn't get your response.</Say>
    <Redirect>screen-caller.xml</Redirect>
</Response>
```

handle-screen-input.php:

```
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

    echo '<Response>';

    $user_pushed = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'];

    if ($user_pushed == 1)
    {
            echo '<Say>Connecting. Calls are recorded.</Say>';
    }
    else {
            echo '<Hangup />';
    }

    echo '</Response>';
```

voicemail.php:

```
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
?>
<Response>
    <?php if ($_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'] == 'completed') { ?>
            <Hangup/>
    <?php } else { ?>
            <Say>Please leave a message at the beep.  Press the star key when finished.</Say>
            <Record transcribe="true" action="goodbye.php" transcribeCallback="voicemail-send.php?email=<?php echo $email; ?>" maxLength="120" finishOnKey="*" />
            <Say>I did not receive a recording.</Say>
            <Redirect>voicemail.php</Redirect>
    <?php } ?>
</Response>
```

Comment: Could you post your `voicemail.php` too? Just to see what should happen. Thanks

Comment: @philnash Any updates from your end?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think I have the right idea now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[[ edit ]]**

Ahhh! I know what it is! The below answer (which I've kept for posterity) is straight wrong.

When the person being dialled and getting the whisper hangs up, then the `action` on the `<Dial>` verb is called. From the documentation, [the `DialCallStatus` values can be](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-dial-call-status-values): completed, busy, no-answer, failed or canceled. When the person picks up the phone the status cannot be busy, no-answer, failed or canceled. So when they hang up before the whisper is over, the call status will be completed.

So, when your action gets called, the `DialCallStatus` will be completed and your voicemail.php will hang up.

You do also get sent a `DialCallDuration`, so you could check how long the call went on for and work out whether the call was connected or the person just hung up.

Hope this helps now!

**[[ original answer ]]**

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you hang up during the whisper part of the call then the original caller will continue to make their way through the TwiML they were given. In this case, you only give them a `<Dial>` verb, so once you hang up on your end, the caller completes the `<Dial>` action, gets to the end of their TwiML and hangs up.

Try adding a `<Redirect>/voicemail.php?email=aaron</Redirect>` after the `<Dial>` in the first TwiML.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Just tried that, the call still hangs up for the incoming caller if the call screener just hangs up after answering.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, let me ask around

Comment: Ah yes, that did the trick!  Only hanging up completed calls that are longer than 30 seconds seems to work for most circumstances.

Comment: Hooray! Sorry that took a while to come to, glad it's sorted now.